# Add text with number of observations on facet diverging bar chart

Tags: r, geom-bar

I would like to show the text of the number of observations as shown on the bar chart for the range values that are above and below the mean.

I tried the following

using the Electric Vehicles dataset

light data wrangling to remove spaces and -

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/mohamedalishiha/electric-vehicles?select=evdataset.csv

```
EV <- read_csv("evdataset.csv")


 EV$range_norm <- round((EV$ElectricRange - mean(EV$ElectricRange))/
                          sd(EV$ElectricRange),2)

 EV$range_type <- ifelse(EV$range_norm > 0, "above", "below") 

 EV <- EV[order(EV$range_norm), ] 

 EV$Make <- factor(EV$Make, levels = EV$Make)
```

```
ggplot(EV, aes(x = reorder(Make,range_norm), y = range_norm,
               label = range_norm)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(fill = range_type)) +
  geom_text() +
  facet_wrap(vars(as.factor(Drive))) +
  coord_flip()
```

I was expecting something like this but for the number of observations of each bar..

[image]

Comment: I think the code to convert `Make` to a factor should read `EV$Make <- factor(EV$Make, levels = unique(EV$Make))`. I get an error regarding duplicated levels otherwise.

Comment: I came across that error earlier but have not been able to recreate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)
EV <- read_csv("evdataset.csv")
EV$range_norm <- (EV$`Electric Range` - mean(EV$`Electric Range`))/sd(EV$`Electric Range`)

EV$range_type <- ifelse(EV$range_norm > 0, "above", "below") 

plot_data <- EV |> group_by(Make, Drive, range_type) |> 
  summarize(count = n()) |> 
  mutate(count = ifelse(range_type == "above", count, -count)) |> 
  ungroup()

plot_order <- plot_data |> 
  group_by(Make) |> 
  summarize(totalcount = sum(count)) |> 
  arrange(totalcount) |> 
  pull(Make)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = fct_relevel(Make, plot_order),
                      y = count,
                      fill = range_type,
                      label = count)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(size = 3) +
  facet_wrap(~Drive) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("Make")
```

[image]

Comment: That's really close.
I was looking to facet wrap by drive as well..

EV %>% group_by(range_type,range_norm,Drive) %>% count(Make) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(Make,range_norm), y = range_norm,
               label = range_norm)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity',aes(fill = range_type)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=n)) +
  facet_wrap(vars(as.factor(Drive))) +
  coord_flip()

Comment: Just updated with faceting by Drive

Comment: That's it! although when I run it I get the following error:   Error in `chr()`:
! Can't splice S3 objects

Comment: It's working for me. That error often happens if you're only running part of the `ggplot2` code. Make sure you don't have extra line breaks and are running the full line starting with `ggplot(...`

Comment: Interesting... when I remove plot_order from the aes it works just fine.. wondering if it's because I already had the make ordered by range_norm? Regardless, Thank you for your help on this. Showing the count helps with my project.

Comment: Not sure. If you take that out the order of the bars will change and might be less readable. Try restarting R and then running my code.